# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) - Can't reference a class

Tags: c#, .net-core

So, I'm doing some Angular + .NET Core course on Udemy and I stumbled upon a certain problem: I can't reference a class from ClientApp subfolder. I created an Angular + .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019. My backend app is in route folder and the frontend app is in subfolder ClientApp of my backend app. Here are the screenshots of everything:

AuthController:
[image: AuthController]

UserForRegisterDTO:
[image: UserForRegisterDTO]

Solution Explorer:
[image: Solution Explorer]

What am I getting wrong here?

EDIT:
Out of some reason, I can see every folder in my namespace when I start typing but ClientApp. Here's the screenshot: [image: Not seeing folder]

Answer (score 0):

If you check your IDE, it clearly shows that it cannot find `DatingApp.SPA.ClientApp` namespace.

Open your `UserForRegisterDTO.cs` file and check which namespace it is in. Then add that namespace instead of the one causing the issue.

If you are using Visual Studio (and it looks like you are), go with the cursor to the place in the method where `UserForRegisterDTO` type is underlined and press `Ctrl + .`. It suggest ways of fixing this error, most probably automatically telling you which namespace is missing.

If neither works, please update your question with more details.

Comment: I already tried all of that and I got nothing. The thing is, ClientApp is a folder and DTOs is a subfolder in it, just like DatingApp.SPA.Data I'm using in AuthController where Data is a folder. I don't get it, why DatingApp.SPA.Data works and DatingApp.SPA.ClientApp does not?

Comment: I fixed it! Out of some God know reason, I had in my DatingApp.SPA.csproj some instructions to ignore that precise class. I don't know how it got there. Once I removed it, everything worked flawlessly. Thank you for your time.